# How to nest the output of FindRoot in a table of Derivative evaluations?

Tags: equation-solving, functional-style

I am using ParametericNDSolveValue to numerically solve an ODE system, which I then use to find the definite integral of one of the variables in the solution for different values of a parameter. Here is a simpler (and faster!) version of my code:

```
eqns={y''[t] + d y[t] == 3 a Sin[y[t]], y[0] == y'[0] == 1};
pfun[din_]:=ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns/.{d-> din}, With[{b=1},b NIntegrate[y[t],{t,0,5}]],{t,0,5},{a}];
```

which if plotted for three values of "d" looks like this

[image]

I am using FindRoot to find the "a" values at which these curves meet the line y=3.

```
Table[a /. FindRoot[pfun[din][a] == 3.0, {a, 0, 2}], {din, 1, 3, 1}]
```

What I would like to do next is find the value of the first derivative at each of these points (with the ultimate aim of plotting the derivatives w.r.t. the d parameter values used to make each curve). What I'm stuck on is: do I 
(1) first generate a list of "a" values using the code above and then somehow plug each element into code like this

```
Evaluate[Table[Derivative[1][pfun[din]][a], {din, 1, 3, 1}]]
```

(I'm not clear how to get the derivative function to call a subsequent element in the list for each din value).

or do I  (2) embed the FindRoot function somehow into the derivative function? (I don't know how to do this, or do I use Table or Map?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not completely understand your question but I would do the following by changing little bit from your definitions.

```
eqns = {y''[t] + d y[t] == 3 a Sin[y[t]], y[0] == y'[0] == 1};
pfun[din_] :=ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns /. {d -> din}, 
    With[{b = 1}, b Integrate[y[s], {s, 0, 5}]],{t, 0, 5}, {a}];
```

Then we will simply use a `Module` to write function that depending on the value of `din` will find the derivative at the point where function takes the value of $3$.

```
fun[din_?NumericQ] := Module[{arg, a},
 arg = a /. FindRoot[pfun[din][a] == 3.0, {a, 0, 2}];
 Evaluate[Derivative[1][pfun[din]][arg]]
 ];
Plot[Evaluate@fun[din], {din, 1, 6}, Frame -> True,FrameLabel -> {d, y'[3]}]
```

[image]

However parabolic type of the derivatives is realistic if you crosscheck the slope of the tangents in the following plot.

[image]

**Code for the tangent plot:**

```
Clear[tangent];
tangent[din_, eps_] := Module[{arg, der, c, a, cval},
 arg = a /. FindRoot[pfun[din][a] == 3.0, {a, 0, 2}]; 
 der = Evaluate[Derivative[1][pfun[din]][arg]];
 cval = c /. Flatten@NSolve[der *arg + c == pfun[din][arg], c];
 Plot[Evaluate@(der*x + cval), {x, arg - eps, arg + eps},PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.7], Red, Thick, Dashed],
  Epilog -> {Directive[Opacity[.5], Black], PointSize[Large],Point[{arg, 3.}]}
  ]
 ];
tans = Table[tangent[din, .2], {din, 1, 6, 1}];
opt = Epilog -> ( Options[#, Epilog][[1, 2]] & /@ tans);
Show[{Plot[Evaluate@(Table[pfun[i][t], {i, 1, 6, 1}]), {t, 0, 5}, 
Frame -> True]}~Join~tans, opt]
```

In case this solution does not work for you feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you!! that worked perfectly :-)

Comment: Hi there, when trying this code with my larger system of ODEs I find that Derivative is always giving values below one even though the curves (and tangents) are similar to the ones you have plotted above (i.e. slopes should be greater than one). Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: I can not comment on this issue until I see the larger system. However my approach should work seamlessly as far as mathematics is concerned.